# Мой код застревает в блоке catch

Tags: java

Я должен записывать числа из одного файла в другой. И в процессе мой код застревает в блоке `catch`

```
    BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName1));
    BufferedWriter bW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName2));

    List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String word = "";

    while (bR.ready()) {
        int data = bR.read();
        char c = (char) data;
        if (c == ' ') {
            for (Character character : list) {
                word += character;
            }

            list.clear();

            try{
                int i = Integer.parseInt(word);
                System.out.println(i);
                bW.write(i);
                bW.write(" ");
                word = null;
            } catch(Exception e){
                continue;
            }

        } else{
            list.add(c);
        }
    }

    bR.close();
    bW.close();
}
```

Comment: При чем тут xcode

Comment: Не должен? Зачем так издеваться над `try-catch`?...

Comment: @dmtr человек к сожалению не знает прямого применения `try-catch`  но мы ему поможем.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую заменить функцию `Integer.parseInt();` на 
`Integer.tryParse(word,0);`

```java
public int tryParse(String value, int defaultVal) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return defaultVal;
    }
}
```

В блоке **catch** выводите сообщение ошибки `e.printStackTrace();` или же так `System.out.println(e.toString());` ну и еще один вариант более краткого отображения `System.out.println(e.getMessage());`

В итоге ваш **catch** должен выглядеть так

```java
catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
   continue;
}
```

В таком случае вы сможете узнать причину.

Вы кончено можете просто пропустить ошибку с помощью `continue` но не стоит этого делать, лучше разобраться в ее причинах и создать соответствующий код для решения проблемы, во время чтения вы встретили неверные значения, уведомите об этом пользователя. И попросите исправить либо если логика позволяет исправьте самостоятельно.

Answer (score -2):

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(word);
```

Уверен, что тут вы в `int` пытаетесь положить строку, которая содержит не только числа, например, в строке появляются переносы строки или еще что-то. Поэтому у вас возбуждается исключение и вы постоянно попадаете в блок `catch`.

Comment: Используется `Integer.parseInt()` вполне естественно передавать туда строку

Comment: А вы уверены, что в строке числа? Я нет.

Comment: Минусаторы, обосновать свой минус можете?

Comment: я тоже не уверен по этой причине предложил код который это проверит

Comment: @VdovinDaniil "111!!!один1" строка, но при парсинге выдаст исключение